# Can I use a AngularJs template in a kendo multiselect itemTemplate and tagTemplate?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have an AngularJs template that I would like to re-use with my Kendo Multiselect Item Template and Tag Template.

Is there any way to do this? I'm not sure how to pass data. When I just try to use AngularJS templates, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI templates are just a javascript functions which accepts single parameter - objects to render and return rendered html.

AngularJS template is an HTML fragment which is rendered by [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service and stored by [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache).
It is theretically possible but hard way.